# How do I give SSH access to users for particular subdomains in cPanel

Tags: ssh, subdomain, cpanel, centos7, whm

I am currently setting up a dev environment with multiple subdomains dom1.domain.net, dom2.domain.net, dom3.domain.net etc. and I would like to give different users SSH access to the individual subdomain directories in the file system. Some instances may allow more than one user access to the subdomain directory and some instances may allow one user to have access to multiple subdomain directories.

So, the question is: Is there a way for me to give multiple cPanel users SSH access per subdomain dir?

I tried to add a 'subdomain' account through WHM's 'Create account' but as expected it failed since the base domain already exists on the same server.

Anyone have any ideas? Point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
The reason for this setup is that I want to setup git for different subdomain enviroments and want to give users access only to the server projects directories they are concerned with.

Comment: It would be much appreciated if the person who downvoted this question give a reason as to why? Maybe even how I could improve the post? Thanks.

Comment: If you like work with diferents subdomain how accounts, must be delete before, all subdomains on cpanel account. After delete subdomians on domains account, you can create new accounts with each subdomain without problems. On Cpanel, every account it's an account of system. Impossible diferents system accounts on one account of cpanel. I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to WHM you could just create individual cPanel accounts for each subdomains.

If you give access via SSH to a cpanel user, that user will have access to the main domain setup on the cPanel account and on all the subdomains created in that account. So in the end if you will have a cPanel user that can access 1-5-10 or whatever is the total of subdomains.

You can create multiple FTP accounts and associate them with subdomains but you won't be able to login via SSH with a FTP account.

Comment: I bought shared hosting can i do it? If yes then where is an option for creating a Cpanel account for subdomain?

Comment: I believe this might be of interest: https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/preferences/user-manager/